# Создания таблицы переходов на языки си

Tags: c, функции, указатели

Есть набор функций примерно 100 шт. Каждая функция имеет свою мнемонику. Грубо говоря функция `void ADD(void)` имеет мнемонику `0x00`, `void cos(void)` — `0x10`, и так далее.

Цель всея деяния, создание переходов между исполняемым файлом в котором прописаны все основные мнемоники функций и вызовом функций исполнителей.

Городить через

```c
switch () {
    case
}
```

можно, но это сложно.
Охота сделать таблицу переходов? Чтобы можно было связать мнемоники с функциями, и вызывать функцию по коду мнемоники.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что-то такое годится?

```
typedef void (*func)(void);

typedef struct _Func {
    int code;
    func f;
} Func;

Func fn[] = {{0,ADD}, {0x10,cos}};

void call(int code)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(fn)/sizeof(fn[0]); ++i)
        if (fn[i].code == code) { fn[i].f(); break; }
}
```

Если диапазон кодов небольшой...

```
typedef void (*func)(void);

func fn[] = { ADD, // Для 0
              NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
              NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
              cos // Для 0x10
             }

// Или, с С99 (спасибо eanmos):
// func fn[] = { [0] = ADD, [0x10] = cos };

void call(int code)
{
    if (fn[code]) fn[code]();
}
```

Comment: А без цикла for ?

Comment: Если диапазон кодов небольшой - можно просто массив указателей на функции, где код - просто индекс в массиве, и вызывать, обращаясь к массиву. См. дополненный ответ. Если диапазон большой, так что массив огромный - то или switch, или for.

Comment: @Harry, начиная с C99 появилась инициализация массива с designator: `int n[5] = {[4]=5,[0]=1,2,3,4}; // holds 1,2,3,4,5`. Вот ссылка на [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization). Можете дополнить ответ для полноты.

Comment: @eanmos Спасибо; посмотрите - я верно в ответе дописал?...

Comment: Если диапазон кодов большой, то отлично работает хэш-таблица

Comment: @Harry, да, только вы изначально скобки перепутали) `func[] fn` → `func fn[]`.

Comment: @eanmos Мда... Поспешишь - людей насмешишь :)

Comment: А как можно инициализировать массив 'func fn[]' в .c файле. Создал массив 'func fn[] ' в .h файле. А как инициализировать его в .c файле?